# Split panda frames when a specific column reaches a given value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to `df.cut()` with two different bin sizes for two specific parts of a dataframe. I believe the easiest way to do that is to read my dataframe and split it in two so I can use `df.cut()` in the two independent dataframe with two independent bins.

I understand I can use df.head(), but I had to keep changing the dataframe and they don't have always the same size. For example, with the following dataframe

```
               A     B
          1    0.1   0.423655
          2    0.2   0.645894
          3    0.3   0.437587
          4    0.31  0.891773
          5    0.4   0.1773
          6    0.43  0.91773
          7    0.5   0.891773
```

I want to have two dataframes for value of A higher or equal than 0.4 and lower than 0.4.

So I would have df2:

```
                 A     B
          1    0.1   0.423655
          2    0.2   0.645894
          3    0.3   0.437587
          4    0.31  0.891773
```

and df3:

```
                 A      B
           1    0.4   0.1773
           2    0.43  0.91773
           3    0.5   0.891773
```

Again, df.head(4) or df.tail(3) won't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df2 = df[df["A"] < 0.4]
df3 = df[df["A"] >= 0.4]
```

Answer (score 1):

I added in some ficticious data as an example:

```
data = {'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], 'B': [5,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1 = df[df.A > 4]
df2 = df[df.A <13]

print(df1)
print(df2)
```

Output

```
>>> print(df1)
   A   B
4  5  11
5  6  12
6  7  13
7  8  14
>>> print(df2)
   A   B
0  1   5
1  2   8
2  3   9
3  4  10
4  5  11
5  6  12
6  7  13
7  8  14
```

Comment: I've just got a df with false and true, like so:    
                                                             
`1        True
2        True
3        True
4        True
5       False
6       False`

Comment: I don't know how to properly write the dataframe in the comments. But I didn't get the result I wanted as exemplified in my question.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not. I don't know the values of `df['B']` beforehand. Only `df['A']`

Comment: I've corrected my code.  I think this should work now if you're looking for two separate dataframes.

Comment: Did this answer your questions ziulfer?

Comment: Thanks for help @wolfblitza. I think there is still a problem with your code. df2 = df[df.A <13] should 4 instead of 13 right? I didn't test your answer, but the accepted answer by CanisLupusOccidentali worked like a charm. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd 
data = {'A': [0.1,0.2,0.1,0.2,5,6,7,8], 'B': [5,0.2,4,8,11,9,10,14]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df2 = df[df.A >= 0.4]
print(df2) 

#    A     B
#4  5.0  11.0
#5  6.0   9.0
#6  7.0  10.0
#7  8.0  14.0

df3 = df[df.A < 0.4]
print(df3) 


#     A    B
#0  0.1  5.0
#1  0.2  0.2
#2  0.1  4.0
#3  0.2  8.0
```